# how to change document.createElement value?

Tags: javascript, scripting, greasemonkey

I'm troubleshooting a java script witch creates a web page. It uses this sequence:

```
aTD=document.createElement("TH");
header.appendChild(aTD);
```

the problem is that in some point of the script, this goes as:

```
 aTD=document.createElement("<TH>");
 aTD.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a4Phrase.TOTAL));
 header.appendChild(aTD)
```

in IE this is not one issue. But in Firefox the page creation fails at this point so only half of the page is displayed. I've tried in last days to figure out one solution but no sucess. So here is my question:

How can I change(*using greasemonkey*)

```
aTD=document.createElement("<TH>");
```

to

```
aTD=document.createElement("TH");
```

?

Comment: Verify that this is not your web page, and that you merely hope to use Greasemonkey to get the page to work in Firefox.   Note that depending on the page, this may not be something that Greasemonkey can easily do.  Provide a link to the target page or pastebin.com its source.

Comment: It's not my web page but the "error" comes in one web toll used at office(not available from outside). It works only with IE at the moment

Comment: You can pastebin the source and we could see if GM can help.  In general, GM can overwrite the page's JS -- but only after most of the page has loaded (usually too late).  There are kludge-arounds (search here at SO), but the best approach depends on the details.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a dirty hack and I suppose your problem can be solved in some another more accurate way. However you can just proxy `document.createElement` method:

```
var ce = document.createElement;
document.createElement = function(el){
    if (el === '< TH>') {
        el = 'TH';
    }
    return ce.call(document, el);
};

var aTD=document.createElement("< TH>");
aTD;
```

Comment: If this truly is a Greasemonkey application, then this code will not work.  Even modified correctly for GM, the code will likely not be able to fire in time.   The OP needs to clarify and specify.

Comment: it seems that this script produces no effect with Greasemonkey. thanks